# Javascript: Finding a certain Element and ripping off parts of the link

Tags: javascript

I am totally new to JavaScript coding, and I hope you can help me.

In my source code there is a link with the content `shortlink` in its attribute.

```
<link rel='shortlink' href='http://example.com/?p=14286' />
```

From this element I want to read out the href link, and rip off everything before the `?p=14286` query.

How is this possible? Using `document.getElementsByAttribute` I failed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just `split` the URL.

```
var link = document.querySelector("link"); //use All for a list
var link = link.href.split("?");
var url = link[0];
var params = link[1];
```

Answer (score 3):

You can select any elment by its attributes using the css attribute selector [attribute=value].

So you can get the href URL with this statement:

```
document.querySelector("link[rel=shortlink]").href
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://devdocs.io/dom/document/queryselectorall) to find all elements matching a CSS selector, and use a CSS3 attribute selector to find all elements with the specified string in their rel attribute.

As for getting the part of the link you want, it's basic string manipulation which has many answers and resources on this site and elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the HTML then add an id to the link and use `document.getElementById`.  If you can't then get all links with `document.getElementsByTagName` and search for `rel='shortlink'`.

```js
// Get all link tags
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('link');

// Search link tags for rel='shortlink'
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  var link = links[i];
  if (link.getAttribute('rel') == 'shortlink') {
    var href = link.getAttribute('href');
    var query_start = href.indexOf('?');
    var query = href.substring(query_start);
    alert(query);
    break;
  }
}

// Alternatively we can use an id
var myLink = document.getElementById('myLink');
var href = myLink.getAttribute('href');
href = href.substr(href.indexOf('?'));
alert(href);
```

```html
<link rel='shortlink' href='http://example.com/?p=14286' />
<link rel='otherlink' href='http://example.com/?p=12345' />
<link rel='otherlink' href='http://example.com/?p=12345' id="myLink"/>
```